# How to access to the Outer class's field from Inner class of same name in C#? (nested-class)

Tags: c#, nested-class

How can I access to the field of outer class from inner class if the name of parameter is same as the outer class's field name?

For example -

```
class OuterClass
{
    static int Number;

    class InnerClass
    {
        public InnerClass(int Number)
        {
            Number = Number;   // This is not correct
        }
    }
}
```

So I tried like below -

```
class OuterClass
{
    static int Number;

    class InnerClass
    {
        public InnerClass(int Number)
        {
            this.this.Number = Number;   // Gives compiler error
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access it, please help ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for

```
class OuterClass
{
    static int Number;

    class InnerClass
    {
        public InnerClass(int Number)
        {
            OuterClass.Number = Number;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should only work on `static` classes or am I missing something?

Comment: only static yes, all other one need a reference to an instance

Answer (score 1):

Since it is `static`, you can just access it by writing: `OuterClass.Number = Number;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something in the lines of this:

```
Public InnerClass
{
    private MainClass _mainclass;

    public InnerClass(MainClass mainclass)
    {
         this._mainclass = mainclass;
    }


}
```

This way, you always create the inner class with a reference to the parent class and can call it with `mainclass`.